# how do i convert combobox string values to integer to be parsed into mysql database in c#

Tags: c#, mysql, combobox

as the heading says how do i convert say two string values (Active and In-Active) in a combobox upon selection of In-Active increases value of database column default value under column iActive from 0 to 1. so far i tried Convert.Toint32 and changed my stored procedure as

```
CREATE 
DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` 
PROCEDURE `sp_edit_user`
(
    pUserID INT(11),
    pEmployee_Name VARCHAR(15), 
    pUser_Name VARCHAR(15), 
    pRole VARCHAR(15),
    piActive INT(1)
)
BEGIN
    UPDATE t_user_auth SET Employee_Name = pEmployee_Name, User_Name = pUser_Name, Role = pRole, iActive = piActive + 1
    WHERE UserID = pUserID;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

and code is

```
private void kryptonbtnSaveEdit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Pigen"].ConnectionString;
    using (MySqlConnection cnn = new MySqlConnection(connectionString))
        using (MySqlCommand cmd = cnn.CreateCommand())
        {
            try
            {
                cnn.Open();
                cmd.CommandText = "sp_edit_user";

                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
          //      MessageBox.Show((comboBox1Status.SelectedValue), "");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pUserID", Convert.ToInt64(lbluserID.Text));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pEmployee_Name", txtboxEmploy.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pUser_Name", txtboxuser.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pRole", comboBox2Role.SelectedItem.ToString());
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@piActive", Convert.ToInt32(comboBox1Status.SelectedValue));

                //if(comboBox1Status.SelectedText != "Active")
                //{
                //    int m = Int32.Parse("In-Active");
                //}
```

what i notice is all values are increased from 0 to 1 even if selection is still on Active, probably from my stored procedure iActive + 1. how do i write this to accept In-Active as value 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably you can do this by conditional operator :

```
 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@piActive", ((comboBox1Status.SelectedText == "Active") ? 1 : 0));
```

This will set `@piActive` as 1 if "Active" is selected else set `@piActive` as 0.

Comment: The `Convert.ToInt32` isn't neccessary. `1` and `0` are already ints.

Comment: it works only when converting from Active to In-Active but can't convert from In-Active back to Active

Comment: why you have used `iActive = piActive + 1` ? you can use directly `iActive = piActive ` now..

Comment: yes i've changed it from `iActive = piActive + 1` to  `iActive = piActive `  and from your edited code when u change from In-Active to Active you cant change back to In-Active

Comment: and in my database default value is 0 (Active)

Comment: Its solved now ty, it had to do with the string `"Active"` so I changed it to `"ACTIVE"`